ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor not sending scheduled tasks under 99% CPU load
In a highly scalable product, I'm using ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor to send delayed events, one for every incoming message. The delay is around 1 second.
Under very high CPU load, the scheduler sends the events at a very low rate. Even though hundreds of events should be sent per second, it barely sends 10, sometimes 1 or 2.
This is the configuration
    private final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor deliveryReceiptExecutorService =
        new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(50, threadFactory);

My guess is that the CPU is so busy that the threads handling the scheduled events don't get the chance to run.
Question: can somebody recommend a better approach to guarantee at least some balance between the incoming events and the outgoing delayed events? Based on the logs from the scheduler class, after one hour of running the process, completedTaskCount is equal to 300k and taskCount is equal to 3M, 10 times more.
Update:
I'm using ECS in AWS to run tasks with 1 vCPU and 4 GB of memory. The idea behind my test is to see what happens when there's a spike of traffic and if something can be done to make sure that the events are sent in real-time, without significant delays.

How many cores?

Note that context switches can kill performance. Ideally you'd have as many worker threads as your CPU has cores. If you want to balance input and output processing you might assign half of the workers to each of those queues and maybe employ some task stealing in case any queue is empty (so give priority to the own queue and use the other if a thread is idle).

I'm using ECS in AWS to run tasks with 1 vCPU and 4 GB of memory. The idea behind my is was to see what happens when there's a spike of traffic and if something can be done to make sure that the events are sent in real-time, without significant delays.

Post details as edits to your Question, not as Comments.

Unburden machine
If your CPU is running at virtually 100% across all cores, and work is not getting done, your computer is overburdened.

Get a more powerful machine with more cores.
Decrease the workload
Install enough RAM to avoid thrashing.

Virtual threads
Given that you merely want a one second delay at the top of every task, you do not really need a ScheduledExecutorService. Just sleep for a second as the first line of code in your task.
Thread.sleep( Duration.ofSeconds( 1 ) ) ;

Then use virtual threads to run your tasks, for possibly better overall performance.
ExecutorService deliveryReceiptExecutorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor() ;

Caveat: Virtual threads are contraindicated if your tasks are CPU-bound or have long-running sections of code that are either native (Foreign Functions, JNI) or synchronized.

I added an update where I explain the goal of my test. Virtual threads sound interesting, I will check them out.

@Cristian Add more cores to your virtual machine. A single core is not enough for your workload.

what you're saying makes sense
